# Make UIScrollView scroll on button click from another ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollview with 3 childViewControllers. 
Is there a way to scroll the UIScrollView from a button on one of those childViewControllers?
I'm not sure how to access the UIScrollView from the child, otherwise i could use setContentOffset.

Edit:

Tried to implement Zhang's answer.

In the ChildViewController

```
protocol ChildVCDelegate {
    func childVC(childVC: MainViewController, scrollButton:UIButton)
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: ChildVCDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.profileButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("informDelegateToScrollMethod"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }

    func informDelegateToScrollMethod(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.delegate?.childVC(self, scrollButton:sender as UIButton)
    }

}
```

Then when i try to add the protocol to to the Controller with the Scroll View:

```
class CustomPagerViewController: PagerViewController, ChildVCDelegate {
    ...
}
```

I get a "Type CustomPagerViewController does not conform to protocol ChildVCDelegate"

Any Ideas?

UPDATE:

I was able to get the View controller to conform but now i am getting a
EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2) error on the line:

```
self.delegate?.childVC(self, scrollButton:sender as UIButton)
```

Is there something i am missing?

Final Update:

I was able to get it working by adding @objc to protocol:

```
@objc protocol ChildVCDelegate {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps protocols can help.

First define a protocol in your child view controller class (ChildVC) like this:

```
@class ChildVC;

@protocol ChildVCDelegate <NSObject>

// methods your receiver delegate need to implement
-(void)childVC:(ChildVC *)childVC didPressButton:(UIButton *)scrollButton

@end

@interface ChildVC: UIViewController
{

}

@property <nonatomic, weak> id<ChildVCDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Then in your ChildVC implementation file:

```
@implementation ChildVC

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    ....
    UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame....];
    ...
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(informDelegateToScrollMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void)informDelegateToScrollMethod:(id)sender
{
    // tell your delegate to execute the delegate method defined in .h file of your ChildVC
    [self.delegate childVC:self didPressButton:sender];
}
```

In your main view controller where the UIScrollView is defined, go to the .h file and `#import "ChildVC.h"` if you haven't already and make your main view controller conform to the ChildVCDelegate

```
#import "ChildVC.h"

@interface MainViewController: UIViewController <ChildVCDelegate>
```

Finally in your view controller where you defined your UIScrollView, you can do what ever you want with your delegate method implementation:

```
@implementation MainViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // tell the childViewController, the mainViewController is the delegate
    // when that button is pressed inside child view controller
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.childViewController.delegate = self;
}

...

// -----------------------------------------------------------
// This is the delegate method that must be implemented
// -----------------------------------------------------------
-(void)childVC:(ChildVC *)childVC didPressButton:(UIButton *)scrollButton
{
    // Put logic to scroll UIScrollView here
    [self.myScrollView setContentOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 100) animated:YES];
}
```

Hopefully that works :D

Comment: I tried to implement this in my code but i am using Swift and having trouble getting the Main View Controller to conform to the protocol. Can you show what the code for this would look like in swift?

Comment: class MyViewController: UIViewController, Protocol1, Protocol2, Protocol3

Comment: Yeah, thats how i have it and i get a "Type CustomViewController does not conform to ChildVCDelegate" error. Im not sure if there is something i am missing, or if the Swift code i have isn't the exact translation of the code you have supplied.

Comment: Edit your question with your new source code trying to conform to the protocol so we can see what's wrong.